# Add value to a textbox dynamically

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" >

        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Add Course_Subject</title>
<style type="text/css">
            <!--
body {
    background-color: #FFCCFF;
}
.style1 {
    color: #0066FF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style2 {font-size: 18px}
.style17 {  font-family: "Monotype Corsiva";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #6633CC;
}
.style19 {color: #000099}
.style21 {color: #000099; font-weight: bold; }
-->
</style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:include page="Log_Admin.jsp"/><br/>
        <form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
        <table width="46%" height="43" border="3" bgcolor="##CCCC99" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="85%" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF99"><label><span class="style17">Course and Subject Information</span></label></td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td>
                <table width="666" height="207" border="0" align="center" bordercolor="#F0F0F0" bgcolor="#CCCC99" >
                    <tr>
                        <td width="186" height="46" align="left"><div align="left"><span class="style19">
                        <label><strong>Coourse ID</strong></label>
                        </span></div></td>
                        <td><label>
                            <select name="cid" size="1" id="cid" align="left" onclick="loaadCourseName()">
                            <option selected="selected">None</option>
                            <option>C001</option>
                            <option>C002</option>
                            <option>C003</option>
                            <option>C004</option>
                            <option>C005</option>
                            <option>C006</option>
                            <option>C007</option>
                            <option>C008</option>
                            <option>C009</option>
                            <option>C010</option>
                            </select>
                        </label></td>
                        <td width="186" height="46" align="left"><div align="left"><span class="style19">
                        <label><strong>Coourse Name</strong></label>
                        </span></div></td>
                        <td width="310" align="left"><input name="cname" type="text" id="cname" size="25" maxlength="50" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="186" height="46" align="left"><div align="left"><span class="style19">
                        <label><strong>Subject ID</strong></label>
                        </span></div></td>
                        <td><label>
                            <select name="sid" size="1" id="sid" align="left">
                            <option selected="selected">None</option>
                            <option>S01</option>
                            <option>S02</option>
                            <option>S03</option>
                            <option>S04</option>
                            <option>S05</option>
                            <option>S06</option>
                            <option>S07</option>
                            <option>S08</option>
                            <option>S09</option>
                            <option>S10</option>
                            </select>
                        </label></td>
                        <td width="186" height="46" align="left"><div align="left"><span class="style19">
                        <label><strong>Subject Name</strong></label>
                        </span></div></td>
                        <td width="310" align="left"><input name="sname" type="text" id="sname" size="25" maxlength="50" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="save" type="submit" id="save" value="Save" onclick="validate(this.form)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
package DBCon;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Nayan
 */
public class searchCourseName extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
    * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String cname=null,courseid;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/online_exam?"+"user=root&password=pass");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

            courseid=request.getParameter("cid");
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select course_name from course where course_id='"+courseid+"'");

            while(rs.next())
            {
                cname=rs.getNString("course_name");
                //String s=rs.getString(1);
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("courseName",cname);
            //RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/ONLINEEXAMINATION/removeCourse2.jsp");
            //requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);

        }
         catch(Exception e) { 
            out.println("<h1>"+e.getStackTrace()+"</h1>");
        }
    } 

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
    * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 

    /** 
    * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
    * Returns a short description of the servlet.
    */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

Now when I select an item in the dropdown `cid` I want to display the corresponding `courname` in the `cname` textfield. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try not just to dump code on the page, give us an explaination.

Comment: There's too much noise in the question. For example, does the same problem still occur when you remove those CSS style declarations? If so then they are totally irrelevant and should be removed from the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove**

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

They are superfluous and dangerous when using JSP. JSP already sets its own content type. When getting the response writer in the servlet, you'll only risk seeing `IllegalStateException` errors in server logs when forwarding to JSP.

---

**Replace**

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("courseName",cname);
//RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/ONLINEEXAMINATION/removeCourse2.jsp");
//requestDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

by

```
request.setAttribute("courseName",cname);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/removeCourse2.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This sets the variable in request scope so that it's available by `${courseName}` and forwards the request back to same JSP where the form is in. The session scope will also work, but you don't want that here. It'll affect other requests (the visitor may for instance have opened the same form in multiple browser tabs).

---

**Update**

```
<input name="cname" type="text" id="cname" size="25" maxlength="50" />
```

with

```
<input name="cname" value="${courseName}" type="text" id="cname" size="25" maxlength="50" />
```

The `${courseName}` will print the value of the request attribute. Doing so in the `value` attribute of the input element will make it to show up in the browser. If this is an user controlled value, you may want to use JSTL `fn:escapeXml()` to avoid XSS attacks.

---

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains a Hello World